# Check that VM on GCP is connecting to GCP VPN Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

How do I confirm that my VM connects to my GCP VPN Gateway? The two are already on the same network. I have tried pinging to the VPN Gateway IP from the vm but I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to review and make sure that:

- The VPN is active under Cloud VPN
- Ensure that your GCP and on-prem firewall are allowing ingress/egress traffic between them
- Depending on the type of VPN you choose, make sure that the IP address of the VM is shared to your on-prem via BPG, Route or Policy

If you see an issue with the VPN, you can review the VPN logs logs via logging (log viewer) and choose GCE Router. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview

If the issue is with the BGP/Route/Policy based, you would need to ensure your VPN IP is part of the shared range on both side (GCP and on-prem). https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#classic-vpn

If the issue is with Firewall, make sure that nothing is blocking your VM from communicating with your VPN IP range on GCP side and on your on-prem side. https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/configuring-firewall-rules

Here is more troubleshooting you can review/try: https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/support/troubleshooting